# Displayinf error on payable in solc

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript, hardhat

This is my transaction file, to interact with the  Eth blockchain, but it is showing me error in payable keyword in solc, can anyone help me with it, please

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

//import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Transactions {
    uint256 transactionCount;

    event Transfer(address from, address receiver, uint amount, string message, uint256 
    timestamp, string keyword);
  
    struct TransferStruct {
        address sender;
        address receiver;
        uint amount;
        string message;
        uint256 timestamp; 
        string keyword;
    }

    TransferStruct[] transactions;

    function addToBlockchain(address payable receiver, uint amount, string memory message, string memory keyword) public {
        transactionCount += 1;
        transactions.push(TransferStruct(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword));

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword);
    }

    function getAllTransactions() public view returns (TransferStruct[] memory) {
        return transactions;
    }

    function getTransactionCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return transactionCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the error message you get to your question.

Comment: Expected token Comma got 'Payable'solc
This the error message I'm getting its on address payable in addToBlockchain funcntion